# Bucle do while javascript

Tags: javascript

quería saber si alguien me podría ayudar, estoy haciendo un ejercicio en javascript en el que recojo cookies os dejo el código:

```
window.onload = function(){
            var contador = 0;
            do{
                contador=contador+1;
                var cookieLeida=getCookie("carrito"+contador);
                //alert(cookieLeida);
                var datos = cookieLeida.split("&");
                //alert(datos);
                insertaCookie(datos[0],datos[1],datos[2],datos[3],datos[4]);
            }while(cookieLeida!="");
        }
```

Lo que hago es asignarle un contador por que mis cookies las almaceno con el nombre carrito y un acumulado, es decir mis cookies son carrito1, carrito2, etc, así hasta las que se almacenentodo me funciona bien y me recoge las cookies sin problemas, pero ademas me devuelve una ultima cookie en blanco por la estructura del do while, mi duda es si alguien me puede decir como hago para impedir que me devuelva esa cookie en blanco o como ignorarla para que no me la muestre por pantalla al añadir los datos de la cookie en un array.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Mejor que usar `alert()`  para debuggear es usar `console.log` , te recomiendo aprender su uso.

Comment: Si tienes alguna manera de saber cuántas cookies hay actualmente, puedes usar un bucle for. Caso contrario, hazlo mediante un while como lo indica la respuesta  de Víctor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Otra posibilidad:

```
window.onload = function(){
        for (var contador = 1; ; contador++ ) {
            var cookieLeida=getCookie("carrito"+contador);
            if(cookieLeida == '') break;
            var datos = cookieLeida.split("&");
            insertaCookie(datos[0],datos[1],datos[2],datos[3],datos[4]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: De esta forma no me recoge ninguna cookie

Comment: Parece que empiezas a contar desde 1.... prueba ahora

Comment: Perfecto, esta vez si me ha funcionado perfectamente , muchas gracias

Comment: +1 una solución más legible.

Answer (score 1):

Una tercera alternativa, sin usar bucles:

```
(function testCookies(contador = 0) {
  var cookieLeida = getCookie("carrito" + contador);
  if (cookieLeida === '') { return; }
  var datos = cookieLeida.split("&");
  insertaCookie(datos[0], datos[1], datos[2], datos[3], datos[4]);
  testCookies(contador + 1);
})();
```

Es una simple IIFE que seguirá ejecutándose mientras hayan cookies.

Comment: Gracias, la apunto para probarla también

Answer (score 0):

Cambiamos el do while, por un while:

```
window.onload = function(){
            var contador = 0;
            var cookieLeida= "cookie";
            while(cookieLeida!=""){
                contador=contador+1;
                var cookieLeida=getCookie("carrito"+contador);
                //alert(cookieLeida);
                var datos = cookieLeida.split("&");
                //alert(datos);
                insertaCookie(datos[0],datos[1],datos[2],datos[3],datos[4]);
            }
        }
```

Metodo sugerido por WC3SCHOOLS:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
   }
    return "";
}
```

---

Explicacion:

El parametro cname sera feemplzado por el nombre de la cookie.

La variable name guardara el nombre de la cookie y su valor. Por eso le comcatenamos el =

Las cookies son un string, por eso proseguimos a decodificarla.

Cremos un array ca donde guardaremos cada pedazo de la cookie decodificada

Con el ciclo for recorremos el array para obtener cada valor de los pedazos de la cookie,este lo asignamos a c

Mientras el primer caracter (chartAt) sea igual a espacio vacio, vamos a cortarlo(substring)

Para continuar utilizamos el indexOf , si devuelve 0, es porque hay un objeto en esa posicion (false seria -1)es decir, se hallaron cookies, procedemos a retornar el valor.

Comment: Convendría declarar e inicializar `cookieLeida` fuera del bucle, no?

Comment: Ese es el problema al hacer el while solo tendría que declarar cookieLeida fuera y me da error

Comment: @leonbloy exacto, y le colocamos un valor temporal.?

Comment: @dgomez,en wc3schools, hay otra forma mas compleja, usando un for

Comment: acabo de probar la solución de @Victor-Random y me sigue sacando una cookie en blanco al final, y no puedo saber cuantas cookies totales tengo ya lo pensé lo de el for pero no se el máximo de cookies, aun que no me sirve del todo la solución agradezco tu ayuda

Comment: @dgomez he actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: Si la 2 función que me has puesto si te das cuenta es la que yo empleo para recoger las cookies, esa función ya la tenia declarada, ya conseguí solucionar el problema con la respuesta de @leonboy, de todas formas gracias por la ayuda